# Spoofing HTTP-request Referrer from HTML?

Tags: html, http, http-headers, httprequest

Is there some secret and mystical way to change the value of my HTTP-request's referer, or at the very least, keep it from showing? Also, using a MitM page from another domain would not solve my issue, as you are now just submitting that other page's value.

This is not browser specific, I would need to do this on the HTML level.

The problem I am facing is a silent-login page where it sends an HTTP-Redirect to the http-Referrer, unless it is the same domain, or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control this on an html level.  Your only option is to modify the login code to not issue the redirect or to direct it to the desired page.

Comment: Yeah I figured I couldn't but felt it was worth asking to see if there was something I didn't know about.

Modifying the login code will probably land me in jail, it's an outside site. ;).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I know how you can do this.  The first way is not guaranteed across all browsers, but you can use `rel=noreferrer`.  AFAIK GC is the only UA to currently support this but it is in the standard.  FX may also, IDK.

The second way is far more reliable, and it involves a cool little hack someone shared with me on IRC:

Basically, construct an iframe from a base64-encoded `data:` URI.  The framed document is to have a script that listens for a `window.postMessage()` and when it gets fed the command with a URL to visit, it executes `window.top.location = msg.data.URI` or however it is that one reads the message.  Sorry I can't recall, I haven't slept for a few days.

Enjoy if you still care.. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to it. I know it's an old question but I appreciate it. I also know there's an HTML5 suggestion going around to extend the forms to deal with this some way.

Comment: NP! Feel free to accept it? :)  Do you mind me asking what project it's for?  Promoting web privacy including circumventing referrer transmission is a big interest of mine.  Are you working on anythjing interesting?

Comment: The Qs 2 years old, I'm not sure what project this was for.